# How to connect Android device to SQL SERVER 2008 R2 on PC

Tags: android, sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection

I have SQL server 2008 R2 on my PC and Android application which have to comunicate with database (Select, Insert, Update, Delete). The problem is that I have no idea how should I do this. I find few similar topics, but I don't get it.
Could someone tell me how to do this step by step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a webservice which gets invoked on Apps request.